# ForEach and a pipeline

Tags: powershell

This is a beginners question. I am pulling a `-Property` information about PDF files in a folder using this simple command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pdf" | Select-Object -Property *
```

and it works perfectly fine.

But when I'm trying to do the same using `Foreach` cmdlet, I'm not getting any results... Can someone tell me where I'm making a mistake?

```
Foreach-Object ($_ in Get-ChildItem)
{If ($_.extension -eq ".pdf") {Select-Object -Property *}}
```

I also tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pdf" | Foreach-Object ($_) {Select-Object -Property *}
```

My goal is to just learn how to use this command, but I'm missing something.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not selecting anything in particular in the foreach except viewing all the existing properties for that file type. You can directly pipe the current pipeline object into the select-object

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder\ChildFolder\*" -Include "*.pdf" |ForEach-Object{ $_ |Select-Object -Property *}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Such a small detail! Thank you! :)

Comment: @kurtz: Not a problem Mate. Enjoy Coding